# Is there an `and` operator (&&) in Scss?

Tags: css, sass

I have this HTML element:

`<button class="Button Button--is-primary Button--is-disabled Button--is-dark-theme">`

And I need to defined in Scss a set of deep selectors like this:

```
.Button {
  // Apply this for all Buttons that are dark theme
  &--is-dark-theme {
    // Apply this for all Buttons that are Dark AND are Primary
    &--is-primary {
      //...
    }
  }
}
```

But, my problem is that rule is going to create this:

`.Button--is-dark-theme--is-primary`

When I actually need:

`.Button--is-dark-theme.Button--is-primary`

Answer (score 1):

I just found this:

```
.Button {
  $self: &;

  // Apply this for all Buttons that are dark theme
  &--is-dark-theme {

    // Apply this for all Buttons that are Dark AND are Primary
    &#{$self}--is-primary {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

Which generates:

```css
.Button--is-dark-theme.Button--is-primary {
  color: red;
}
```

Any better option?